# this is lead to memory leak?

Tags: c, opencv, memory-leaks

I hope if some one can answer my question and clarify the details .

```
IplImage* out;
out = doPyrDown( in, IPL_GAUSSIAN_5x5 );
out = doPyrDown( out, IPL_GAUSSIAN_5x5 );
out = doCanny( out, 10, 100, 3 );
 // do whatever with ‘out’
//
...
cvReleaseImage ( &out );
```

I read in Learning opencv this is not a problem . how is it fine ?!
every method doPyrnDown & doCanny allocate Image and return the address of the Image (it's pointer) .
I know that this situation lead to memory leaks .
if not i think the IplImage structure has a list of addresses dynamically updated during run-time of the program .

Comment: in general you are going to get leak with exceptions always using RAII

Comment: yea that's the normal behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about details of these functions you are using. However, from your description it seems that all these are returning pointer to `IplImage`.

```
out = doPyrDown( in, IPL_GAUSSIAN_5x5 );
out = doPyrDown( out, IPL_GAUSSIAN_5x5 );
out = doCanny( out, 10, 100, 3 );
```

Notice that second and third calls are using the pointer returned by first call. If these functions just return the modified pointer then it is not a memory leak (if you delete that pointer at the end of it's usage). However, if they are returning new pointer then this is sure shot memory leak.

Comment: Thanks ravi . I Imagine the IplImage structure can store sequnce of addresses as a queue .